# Using the Extjs Framework

Tags: extjs

I am required to use the Extjs framework in my next project. So what features are available in it? There are so many javascript frameworks available in the market like the DOJO framework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To learn about different features, just have a look at the [ExtJS Examples](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/) page. It should give you a good initial impression of what's available. There are grids, editable grids, tabbed views, trees, windows and other dialogs, menus, toolbars, etc.

Be aware that all of the functionality shown on the examples is not available out-of-the-box, though - some of them require you to include extensions (plugins) developed by the ExtJS user community.

Comment: @Tommi: These all features are available in Dojo Framework and it is not expensive.It is completely free. So any other new features in ExtJs framework.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the principale avantage of ExtJS is the Store mecanism. you can have a store which hold your data (as a database table) and tell some UI widget to display data from the store.
this is great because:

- you bind your widget to a store, then it automatically update it's ui when element in the store are added/modified/deleted
- you can easily display your data in multiple form without worrying about updating echa place (each widget update itself automatically)

others thing done right:

- event
- ability to extend ExtJS classes

Answer (score 0):

#### How it stands up to competition...

To see how Extjs stands up to its competitors, you could review the impressive comparison chart hosted on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

#### Where to get it...

I'm sure you could find tons of information on http://www.extjs.com/. Keep in mind that you're going to pay a [handsome fee](http://www.extjs.com/store/extjs/) to use Extjs.

#### How to learn it...

If your initial impression is good, you could peel into the [Learning Center](http://www.extjs.com/learn/Main_Page) where you'll find API documentation, tutorials, and more.

Comment: "Keep in mind that you're going to pay a handsome fee to use Extjs."  Or you could always use the open source license for free if applicable (MIT for Ext Core and GPL for the Ext JS widget library).